# Hows lensmaker formula works? if Radius is zero?

Tags: lenses

[image]

I am doing my revision and there's such a question. However, when I tried to plug the values into the lensmaker formula, I find that one of the R is equal to zero, as it is not curved.

$(n_2 -n_1)(1/r_1 - 1/r_2)$

Comment: A flat surface has a radius of infinity, not zero...

Comment: @User58220 that should probably be expanded into an answer

Comment: I don't see what more there is to say:  a simple misunderstanding corrected...